# How do we get the initial capacity of a HashSet?

Tags: java, hashset

How does `HashSet` get initial capacity?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class Demo
{
   static int getCapacity(ArrayList<?> l) throws Exception
   {
      Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
      dataField.setAccessible(true);
      return ((Object[]) dataField.get(l)).length;
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
      System.out.println(getCapacity(a));
      HashSet h = new HashSet(); //in case HashSet what we do
      System.out.println(h.capacity());
   }
}
```

Actually we do not have capacity method in `HashSet` class.  Then how do we get capacity of `HashSet`?  How can we get initial capacity of `HashSet` object?

Comment: Why? What good does it do to know it?

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` does not expose that information.  You can set the initial capacity yourself if you want (e.g., `HashSet h = new HashSet(22);`).  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) indicates that the default capacity is `16`.

Internally, the `HashSet` is just wrapping a `HashMap` via the `HashSet.map` field.  I suppose you could use reflection to grab the `map` field and then interrogate it for the initial capacity.  I can't see why you would want to do this though.

Comment: static int getCapacity(ArrayList<?> l) throws Exception {
      Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
      dataField.setAccessible(true);
      return ((Object[]) dataField.get(l)).length;
    }ArrayList a=new ArrayList();System.out.println(getCapacity(a));-10 like these way.please help me

Comment: @user3444725, what are you trying to say here?  please accept & upvote answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot **directly retrieve** the initial capacity of a HashSet object after it has been created, as the initial capacity is not exposed as a public method or attribute. The HashSet class does not provide a **method to query** the initial capacity once it has been set during initialization.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why do you think that adding an answer to a nine year old question was necessary, telling nothing that hasn’t been said by the existing answer already?

Answer (score -1):

Similar to what the code in the question is already doing for `ArrayList`; with the additional step to retrieve the `Map` stored in the `map` variable:

```
    public static int getCapacity(HashSet<?> s) throws Exception {
        var mapField = HashSet.class.getDeclaredField("map");
        mapField.setAccessible(true);
        var map = mapField.get(s);

        var capMet = HashMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("capacity");
        capMet.setAccessible(true);
        var cap = capMet.invoke(map);

        return (Integer) cap;
   }
```

Must eventually be called with the `--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED` option (see [InaccessibleObjectException: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @61443d8f](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72880838/85421)

Using reflection for this can easily break - it highly depends on implementation (e.g. the `map` variable can be renamed or have its type replaced) - code based on OpenJDK 21.

Comment: BTW this is returning the **actual** capacity, not jus the initial capacity, as asked in the question. (I am also not sure what this is good for)