# InaccessibleObjectException: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @61443d8f

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am new to java and maven so bare with me :)
Using jdk 1.8 along with maven 3.8.5 on intellij IDE. Trying to run a test method where I set my unit test environment variables using Systemstubs like this:

```
@ExtendWith(SystemStubsExtension.class)

class myClass {
@SystemStub
private static EnvironmentVariables variables = Helper.getEnvironmentVariables();
```

and the Helper class function is:

```
public static EnvironmentVariables getEnvironmentVariables() {
        return new EnvironmentVariables()
                .and("username", "admin")
                .and("password", "qwerty")
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
> private final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m
> accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed
> module @15d0c81b
>
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.getFieldValue(EnvironmentVariables.java:243)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.getEditableMapOfVariables(EnvironmentVariables.java:205)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.setEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariables.java:162)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.doSetup(EnvironmentVariables.java:153)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.resource.SingularTestResource.setup(SingularTestResource.java:17)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.jupiter.SystemStubsExtension.setup(SystemStubsExtension.java:88)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.jupiter.SystemStubsExtension.setupFields(SystemStubsExtension.java:110)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.jupiter.SystemStubsExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SystemStubsExtension.java:31)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)    at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
> at
> com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
> at
> com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
> Suppressed: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
> make field private final java.util.Map
> java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m accessible: module java.base
> does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @15d0c81b        at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:180)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:174)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.getFieldValue(EnvironmentVariables.java:243)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.getEditableMapOfVariables(EnvironmentVariables.java:205)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.restoreOriginalVariables(EnvironmentVariables.java:187)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.environment.EnvironmentVariables.doTeardown(EnvironmentVariables.java:158)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.resource.SingularTestResource.teardown(SingularTestResource.java:26)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.resource.Resources.executeCleanup(Resources.java:59)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.jupiter.SystemStubsExtension.cleanupFields(SystemStubsExtension.java:124)
> at
> uk.org.webcompere.systemstubs.jupiter.SystemStubsExtension.preDestroyTestInstance(SystemStubsExtension.java:38)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$12(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks$13(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)       at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeAllAfterMethodsOrCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:268)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePreDestroyCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:257)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.cleanUp(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:146)
> at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.cleanUp(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$cleanUp$9(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.cleanUp(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:87)
> ... 36 more

As the stack trace states, it has something to do with systemstubs. I have tried to add the following parameters to intellij vm parameters and to surefire in pom.xml with no luck

```
--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: It would be helpful to have much more information...for example which JUnit Jupiter version are you using? The whole pom file also which versions of surefire-plugin you are using and which JDK version exactly..also do you use a module-info file? etc. a full log output etc..

Comment: You are *not* using jdk 1.8  when you run into this problem. Neither does your attempted solution match the specified version, as jdk 1.8 
 doesn’t have the `--add-opens` option. Worth reading: https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs/blob/main/README.md